# Wordpress create a new tab on post page - plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I was wondering if you could help me with my plugin.
I want to have another tab on the post creator page for example like the AddToAny plugin.

As shown in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you must know how to do a Custom Post Type. 
Here you have official docs : https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Second, you must know how to add a meta box. 
Here you have the official docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

And here there is a good tutorial about meta boxes : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336

Comment: Thanks fito I will look into them now.